# Rapberry Pi 2 и счетчик воды

Tags: raspberry-pi, счетчики, raspbian

Здравствуйте!

Подключаю импульсный счетчик воды Пульс 15-ИХ к GPIO RPi2 для отслеживания прерываний и учета расхода воды.

Счетчик подключен одним проводом к GPIO, а другой к GND. К примеру, PIN29 и PIN30.

Отлаживал свой скрипт на C# с помощью обычной  кнопки reset, снятой с корпуса ПК и все работало корректно.
Когда подключил вместо кнопки счетчик, RPi ведет себя след. образом:

1. Если подключить к PIN29 и включить pull-up подтяжку, то GPIO всегда фиксирует логический 0. Даже когда геркон счетчика разомкнут.
2. Если подключить к PIN5 (на этом GPIO уже имеется pull-up резистор на 1.8 кОм), то GPIO всегда фиксирует логическую 1. Даже когда геркон счетчика замкнут.

Ключевым моментом, как мне кажется, является сопротивление счетчика. Мультиметр фиксирует ~1.6кОм, естественно, когда геркон замкнут.

**Как заставить RPi отслеживать состояние геркона в учетом вышесказанного?**

[image: Сопротивление при замкнутом герконе]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу на свой же вопрос.

Данная система называется "Намур". У нее нет состояния электрической разомкнутости в исправной работе. В замкнутом и разомкнутом состоянии геркона сопротивление меняется. Сделано так для отслеживания сразу 3 состояний:

1. Геркон замкнут - сопротивление 1.6 кОм
2. Геркон не замкнут - сопротивление 5.6 кОм
3. Линия оборвана - сопротивление бесконечно

Заставить RPi работать с Намур без вскрытия счетчика не представляется возможным. Расчет системы уравнений показал, что впаиваемый параллельно резистор должен быть одновременно < 1кОм и > 8.4кОм, что невыполнимо.

P.s. поменял счетчики и все в порядке теперь.